# Load sharedpreferences not giving me a value

Tags: java, android

Here is my code.

```
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(values,
            MODE_PRIVATE);
    str1 = sharedPreferences.getString("lu121", "test");
    str2 = sharedPreferences.getString("lp5151", "test");
    et_username.setText(str1);
    et_pass.setText(str2);
```

by default str1 and str2 should have values of test but when i open the android application the edittexts are not set as test instead i see a blank. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: What you have looks correct.  Have you tested the values of str1 and str2 by outputing to logcat or a toast?  If so can you post the code that setups the Edit Texts and maybe the xml for that part of the activity?

Comment: Additional information posted. I have checked using just the setText function and instead of putting str1 i put "test" and it showed up. However when i toasted str1 and str2 I got no value.

Comment: Drake.  I'm sorry but I can't see anything wrong with your code.  I also tried the snippet in a test app.  Worked for me.  Have you tried restarting your emulator and also starting it clean?  I know after it has been running for a while it does some weird stuff. If that doesn't work maybe someone else will come along and help.

Comment: have you written values to those preferences at any point? if the preference exists but is then deleted, you could just be retrieving empty strings

Comment: What is `values` ? Also, please include the code where you are writing the preferences. If you save the preference with an empty string, the default value will not be returned - since the preference exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `commit()` to save the values (you didn't include any code where you are writing.

```
...
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("lu", "testlu");
editor.putString("lp", "testlp");
editor.commit();
```